# C++ library equivalent for Java?

Tags: java

What would be the equivalent of a library in C++ for Java? I have some classes I'd like to reuse as a library in multiple projects.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you build a jar file with the classes in, and then add a reference to that jar file on the classpath for both compilation and execution.

See the [Oracle Jar File Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) for more information.